# How to store an AES encryption key safely in C++?

Tags: c++, encryption

I'm using AES for encryption in my client-server application.

Currently, I have simply defined a static symmetric key that is hard coded both in the client and the server.

I'm having a feeling that this isn't really secure, as it shouldn't be too difficult to get the key by reversing / disassembling the executable.

On the other hand, I do not see how a key exchange like Diffie-Hellman can solve the problem, as the key will end up in memory on the client and can (probably) be extracted by some method as well.

I'm reading everywhere that all of that, including encrypting and/or obfuscating the key, is not secure. But how is it done securely?

Comment: Using an asymmetric cryptography algorithm, which means each part doesn't know the other's part private key. It's pure math.

Comment: @jweyrich this isn't going to prevent key discovery through disassembly though, is it?

Comment: @jweyrich This will only prevent a person on the network to find out the key, but not someone who has access to the machine.

Comment: If the user controls the machine running your program, there's hardly anything you can do to prevent them from simply reading your memory. Another question is against whom is that encryption supposed to protect?

Comment: @user66875: which seems to be enough for the scenario you described - `client-server application`, but you're right - I don't know what you're trying to protect: the conversation or the key itself for some other purpose. If your device has support for [TPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module), you might leverage that to protect the keys.

Answer (score 6):

Cryptography cannot protect software from users.

If a user has the privilege to run your code, he has the privilege to see the opcodes and therefore discover all information in the code.

Cryptography can protect users from other users.

It's probably time to re-examine the use case. What are we actually trying to achieve here?

Are we trying to protect a proprietary protocol stream, or are we protecting users' identity and data?

For the former, you'll need a lawyer (and deep pockets). For the latter, well-implemented public/private key encryption will suffice.

Answer (score -3):

is your key size fixed say 128 byte or 256 byte. if yes, then you can define a structure for your key data. and then store it in a file which is opened in binary mode.

If No, then you must store the size of key in file then key data.

Comment: You haven't answered the question OP asked: `But how is it done securely?`.